# Powershell - Get-AdUser: Exclude users in array

Tags: powershell

I want to generate a list of users, with the exception of a list of names. This exclusion list changes from week to week.

```
$exclude = @('smith, bob', 'jones, tom', ...)
$csvmaster = @()
$uacct = 'User Account'
$UserID = 'User ID'
$lastname = 'Last Name'
... other attributes

$ulist = get-aduser -filter {enabled -eq 'true'} -properties * | ? {$_.Distinguishedname -like '*Standard User*' -and $_.title -ne $null -and $_.employeenumber -ne $null}  

foreach ($u in $ulist)
{
    if ($u.name -notmatch $exclude) {
    $csvline = New-Object System.Object
    $csvline | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name $UserID -value $u.EmployeeNumber
    $csvline | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name $lastname -value $u.surname
    ...other attributes
    $csvmaster += $csvline
    }
}  
...Output to csv
```

When I run this, the names I want to exclude still make it into the list. I also tried `-notcontains` and excluding them like this:

```
$ulist = get-aduser -filter {enabled -eq 'true'} -properties * | ? {$_.Distinguishedname -like '*Standard User*' -and $_.title -ne $null -and $_.employeenumber -ne $null -and $_.name -notmatch $exclude}
```

This behaves the same way.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So I think my problem was the way `Get-ADUser` accepts input value. And/Or my logic in general. I changed the code to this:

```
$exclude = @( ..list..of..names..)
$csvline = @()
$ulist = get-aduser ...  

foreach ($u in $ulist)
{
    if ($exclude -notcontains $u.name)
    {
        ...
        $csvline += $u.name
    }    
}
```

And it is doing what I need.